# OpenCV contours and hierarchy

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to find characters as contours as in example:

[image]

```
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(roi,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,9,2)
_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
for cnt in contours:
   x,y,w,h = cv2.rectBounding(cnt)
   cv2.rectangle(roi,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)
```

But I am getting results as not expected, as well characters holes returning as 
contours, I can walk around it with `cv2.contourArea()` width, height but I need it to be done with hierarchy.

[image]

If i change hierarchy mode from `cv2.RETR_TREE` to `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` I am getting one contour per whole window as in example:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your approach to the problem is wrong. You are supposed to invert the binary image and then perform contour operations. This is because the contours are formed only around the white regions.

This is what I did:

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, 1)
```

[image]

Now I performed the contour operation. I used the `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` option to neglect contours inside the letters

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[image]

Now I obtained the bounding box as you wanted:

```
for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)
```

[image]